# How to put a background image on a Bootstrap form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put a background image on my form (like behind the text and inputs, just like a background image of my web site), using the Bootstrap framework but the image appears at the bottom and I want it inside the "container".

My code is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <form....>
            <fieldset>
            .
            .
            .
        </form>
        <img src="cs.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the background image of that container as the image? IE:

```
.container {
    background-image: url("cs.jpg");
}
```

Or you can do it inline:

```
<div class="container" style="background-image: url('cs.jpg');">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: It is working !, it seems like I was editing the CSS stylesheet of bootstrap, doing my own CSS just with .container{ back.... } or puting   <div class... sytle="background-image..."> almost fix the problem, now the thing is that the image appears cuted, it is showed just inside the thumbnail div, but it looks really good!

Comment: @GerardoTarragona Great! (: Btw, you can accept this as the answer by clicking the check mark on the left. Also, if you want the full image to appear then you can just specify the width/height on the element.

Answer (score 2):

or you could try like this..

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and in css like this:

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff url("slide.jpg") center center;/*slide.jpg =>you image*/    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```