# Bootstrap - responsive background image with 3 columns of content on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty implementing a design mockup in Bootstrap 3.3.6

I've attached an image to show conceptually what I'm trying to do:

[image]

The blue background is an image. The grey areas are text boxes (one of which also contains a form) that are "on top" of the background image. The whole thing needs to be responsive.

I started by looking at [How to put a background image on a Bootstrap form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924002/how-to-put-a-background-image-on-a-bootstrap-form) and [Responsive Form on top of Responsive Image? - Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294236/responsive-form-on-top-of-responsive-image-bootstrap)

So I added the image (represented by the blue on the above mockup) to a `.container-fluid` as a background image:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1773x555');">
```

The above image is 555px high, but doesn't show fully, because there's no content inside `.container-fluid` to give it height.

So I then added some `div`'s for the 3 grey boxes. I did this by creating 2 `.row` classes and then inserting `.col-md-6` for the boxes to go into. Code below:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1773x555');">

  <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 content">
            <h1>
            Content here
            </h1>
        </div>

  </div>

   <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 content">
         <h1>
            Content here
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 content">
            <h1>
            Content here
            </h1>
        </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I also added a `.content` class to style the grey boxes. These all need to be the same size, although I guess the exact sizes below could be tweaked:

```
.content {
    background-color: #2C3582;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I've set up a  fiddle for it here https://jsfiddle.net/fku5wffn/1/. It doesn't work as intended. Some questions:

1. How do I make the background image so the full height of it is visible (even if there's not enough content inside `.container-fluid`), and so it's responsive?
2. How do I fix the issue with the grey box alignment? I need some space between them, and for them to appear in the positions shown in the mockup. I don't understand why the bottom 2 appear where they do on the fiddle.

Is this even possible, or should I tell the person who designed the mockup it can't be done - especially in a way that will work properly responsively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to try and make the containers like in your picture

```
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.other-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width:100%;
}

div .other-row:after,
div .other-row:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle too : https://jsfiddle.net/dz7cbgdp/2/

For the background-image to appear when there is no content, you can give the `div` a `height`.

Comment: This is pretty good and is a great start for my needs - thank you. The background image is a (rectangular, 16:9 style) photo of some people. Would you suggest using a different image when it goes down to mobile (`.sm` or `.xs` viewports) and maybe swap it with a media query at that breakpoint? Just interested in the best approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: You can use `position:absolute` to move the contents from the image and then give a `height` to the background so it can appear. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/graqfe8b/2/ . But please make sure you do mobile changes using `@media` query

Comment: Another option would be to load the background and an image with the `img` tag, then you display the `img` tag only when it's mobile view.